# How to find the characteristic polynomial of a differential operator $D$ on a vector space of functions with $\cos \theta, \sin \theta$ as basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to find the characteristic polynomial $\Delta(t) $ of a differential operator $D$ on a vector space of functions with $\cos \theta, \sin \theta$ as basis?

I have done some calculations.

$V$ is a vector space of functions with a basis of two functions $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$.

Then
$$
D(\cos \theta) = - \sin \theta, \ \ D(\sin \theta) = \cos \theta
$$

What is the matrix representation $A = [ D ]$?

From this, I can find the characteristic polynomial $\Delta(t) = | A - t I |$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $v_1 = \cos \theta$ and $v_2 = \sin \theta$.

Then
$$
D v_1 = -\sin \theta = 0 v_1 + (-1) v_2
$$
$$
D v_2 = \cos \theta = 1 v_1 + (0) v_2
$$

Thus, the matrix representation for $D$ is
$$
A = [D] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$

The characteristic polynomial for $A$ is given by
$$
\Delta(t) = |A - t I| =
\left| \begin{array}{cc}
 -t & -1 \\
1 & -t \\
 \end{array} \right| = t^2 + 1
$$

Hence, $\Delta(t) = t^2 + 1$.

Solving it, we find that $\pm j$ are the two eigenvalues for the matrix $A$.